# What's the name of this game on the Amstrad that had red-blue separated 3D?

Tags: cpc, identify-this-game

I remember playing a game on the Amstrad 6128 in the '80s or early '90s. It was a space adventure with at least part of the action flying through space and shooting alien ships.

There was an option to view the space-fight scenes in red-blue separated 3D and I think the game came with a pair of 3D glasses. The stars (or possibly just space dust!) were rendered as two separate dots, one red, one blue to simulate the 3D effect as well as the enemy ships.

The "stars" would zoom past your ship as you were flying. I seem to remember that it had full 3D movement, à la *Elite*, although it might have been more limited than that. What's the name of this game?

Comment: I know this is sort of a test question, but a single web search and/or [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) would have this answered already. It really isn't that obscure...

Comment: @jdv - id it's so easy, why not answer? [Wanderer](https://www.mobygames.com/game/wanderer__ "Wanderer") (the one where you traded cats) had 3D in other versions, but I don't remember the CPC one as 3D. [3 Deep Space](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=0000035 "3 Deep Space") never had an Amstrad release.

Comment: @scruss, because answers based _solely_ on web searches are not good answers.

Comment: @jdv I've been searching for this on and off for literally years. I'm sure Wanderer 3D is the right game although I haven't downloaded it yet to verify. What's your simple search that finds it immediately?

Comment: Once assumes the game will be on many lists, including [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Amstrad_CPC_games). If the game had "3D" in the title, then that narrows it down. Typical searches should yield descriptions and images that might jog your memory.

Comment: It looks like such questions are not on-topic even on Gaming.SE. At least, not as presented here (they consider identification questions with "vague descriptions" off-topic.) There doesn't appear to be a site that promotes the notion of identifying "retro" games (again, Gaming.SE specifically says such questions are off-topic.) Then again, it's not just about appropriateness; the notion is to promote good Q&A. And, of course, just because no one else wants such questions doesn't mean they belong here, either.

Comment: I feel that "identify-this-game" questions here should be subject to the same criteria as on Gaming.SE: you need to have some artifact from the game, such as a screenshot, a clip of soundtrack, a blurry photo of the back of the box -- some way to let the person answering the question say with certainty "yes, this is it".

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure if RC wants to be of use it should allow identification questions even with rather vague descriptions. After all, **this** is retrogaming/computing.

Comment: If you want to comment on the suitability of this question, please post an answer on my meta post, which I made before asking this question. This is not the right place for this discussion.

Comment: @Chenmunka are you sure we need that tag? still only one question (this one) tagged with it

Comment: @cat:  Am I sure?  Reasonably.  The discussion at http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/176/is-asking-for-the-title-of-a-retro-game-on-topic covers "Identify This" questions.  Feel free to add to that discussion.  This is not the only tag that has but a single question.  The singular nature should not, of itself, cause a retag.

Answer (score 3):

Wanderer 3D was not with glasses on the Amstrad.

Could it be Relief Action from Loriciel? (http://cpcrulez.fr/GamesTest/relief_action.htm)

Comment: You might be right! The colour separation is the way I remember. I'll check it out/